# How to update OS X when App Store is giving error: "Unable to verify software update.(700)"?

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore, software-update

I'm running OS X 10.13.6 on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018).

App Store shows one available update, "`The macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Supplemental Update 2 for MacBook Pro (2018)`".

Attempting to install update via the App Store GUI results in an error: "`Unable to verify software update.(700)`"

I've also tried installing the update via the terminal which gives the following output:

```
$ sudo softwareupdate --verbose -ia    
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Supplemental Update 2 for MacBook Pro (2018)
Error downloading macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Supplemental Update 2 for MacBook Pro (2018): Unable to verify software update.
Done.

Error downloading updates.
```

Subsequent CLI runs yield:

```
$ sudo softwareupdate --verbose -ia    
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloaded macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Supplemental Update 2 for MacBook Pro (2018)
Installing macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Supplemental Update 2 for MacBook Pro (2018)
Done.

Error installing updates.
```

I've tried deleting the App Store cache folder `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore`, but that didn't change anything.

How can I get the update to install?

Comment: is this you ..MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (2018) computer

Comment: also is this you ..new 17G2037/15P6805, while prior build numbers were 17G2208/15P6703.

Comment: Yeah, the machine is a Touch Bar model with current build 17G2208.